# height and widths are interchanged but app displayed in landscape mode

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6

My mobile game android app should be in landscape mode, when I maximize after minimize the app it will display in landscape mode and screen not rotated, but the problem is height and width are interchanged. So it was displayed half of the screen only remaining was blank screen, if we lock and unlock the device, 
automatically the height and widths are fit according to screen size.

Comment: I handled the above problem using Event.ACTIVATE, if app is active then i reset the width and height. In 4.0, 4.1, 4.2 versions of android it is working fine but when we used 4.4, 5.1 it will shows same problem. How can we rectify this.